# VBA: Cannot add item to combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am trying to add some items via VBA into a dropdown list. Whenever I set the combo variable I get a 13 error.
I don't get to set the combo variable as a combobox from the libro sheet, therefore I cannot use the combobox.additem property, how can I set that straight?

```
Sub Prueba()
Dim libro As Worksheet
Dim combo As ComboBox

Set libro = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tabla Paquetes")
Set combo = libro.Shapes("ComboBox1")

    With combo
        .AddItem "Paris"
        .AddItem "New York"
        .AddItem "London"
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your combo box is NOT a shape, so your code won't find it in the `Shapes` collection.

Instead, do the following:

```vb
Sub Prueba()

    Dim libro As Worksheet
    Dim combo As ComboBox

    Set libro = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tabla Paquetes")
    'Set combo = libro.Shapes("ComboBox1")

    With ComboBox1 ' assuming the name of your control is "ComboBox1"
        .AddItem "Paris"
        .AddItem "New York"
        .AddItem "London"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. But why didn't I have to set a var for the combobox?

Comment: @toku_mo Because it's a named object. The same way you can say, for example, `ActiveWorkbook`.